# Java server memory management on slow networks

Tags: java, networking

I'm writing a code that generates a large XML document and writes it directly into a client stream using StAX XmlStreamWriter.
I'm afraid that if the network becomes extremely slow, the bytes written into the stream will actually stay in memory buffers for a relatively long time and consume a lot of memory on my server.

My question is: is there any way I can keep writing directly to the client stream, and avoid the potential memory problem I described above?

Comment: I'd say, don't look for optimizations unless you know for sure that you have a memory problem.

Comment: The operating system manages the streams and their buffers. There's not much you can do in Java to affect this. Nor should you care; TCP/IP streams have worked for hundreds of thousands of programmers before you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There wouldn't seem to be if you generate faster then you can stream out it has to be in memory. If this does become a major problem you would need to look at a way to move it out of memory such as generating a file but that still needs to be loaded and streamed by something. The main advantage of a file is if you can reuse the file for many requests.

Comment: Yes, this is the best option I know, but I was hoping someone will come with some kind of a magic :)